# Shadow Copies are properly created, but in Explorer I can’t access to “previous versions” (reported as not available)

Tags: snapshot, windows-7-restore, volume-shadow-copy

Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit: I always utilized the shadow copies, not only to restore the OS to a previous version: I mainly use the shadow copies to restore single files, by using the "Previous Versions" tab in the files properties panel.

Today, suddenly, as I attempted to restore a modified file (is the same if I attempt to restore a deleted file), I always get "there are no previous versions available", but I am sure that instead there are previous versions available, because, eg, if I launch the "Shadow Copy View" utility from NirSoft I can access to the previous versions and deleted files, as I am also able to manually restore them.

Furthermore, if from a command prompt I type `vssadmin list shadows`, I can also see the path of the shadow copies, eg 
\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1 and if after I type `mklink /d c:\shadowcopy \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1\` I can directly access shadow copies from Explorer file manager of Windows.

The services for shadow copies (Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider and Volume Shadow Copy) are active, and in restore settings is enabled the option "restore system settings and previous versions of files". But, however, Explorer insists to tell me that "there are no previous versions available" on my files (obviously when, eg, I modify them). What else should I check?